# how to send header with window.open in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
downloadFile = () => {    
    window.open('http://localhost:3000/download','_current')
}
```

how can i send header with this request my header is

```
{headers: {token: Cookies.get('token')}}
```

i have to retrieve this token in backend, kindly someone suggest me the solution for this

//backend route

```
router.get('/download',function(req, res){
    const token=req.headers.token;
})
```

or how to send body through this request

Comment: Use an http library instead. Like axios or request

Comment: this can help. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/related

Comment: There is an open issue for adding support for headers to the window.open function in the HTML standard. Please voice your opinions and needs on there. [https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this with window.open. This can be accomplished with an http client like axios for example. You cannot make http requests with window.open. One of the many ways you could do this :

```
npm install axios
```

in your script:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('http://localhost:3000/download', { headers: { token: Cookies.get('token') } }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Note that this is not the only way , but it does contain the same principle many other http client libraries do.